# Beautiful Soup scraping poorly built table

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to build a scraper to catch league names and odds..Been able to catch the odds but matching the two doesnt seem to work..here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.elitebetkenya.com/coupon.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

for i in soup.findAll("tr"):
    tds =  i.findAll("td")
    fixture = soup.findAll("tr", { "class" : "fixture" })

    try:
        if len(tds[0].text)  != 0 :

            print " Bet-type: %s, Choice: %s, Match code: %s, 1: %s, 0:      %s" % \
          (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text,tds[3].text, tds[4].text)
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something for you to get started.

The markup itself is not that convenient to scrape, but we can rely on the `league` and `fixture` rows to distinguish fixture from fixture and use the [`find_next_siblings()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to get the odds rows from the table.

Complete working example (adjust it for your needs):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.elitebetkenya.com/coupon.php")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")


for league in soup.find_all("tr", class_="league"):
    # get basic league and fixture data
    league_name = league.get_text(strip=True)

    fixture = league.find_next_sibling("tr", class_="fixture")
    home = fixture.find("span", class_="home").get_text(strip=True)
    away = fixture.find("span", class_="away").get_text(strip=True)

    date = fixture.br.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()

    print(league_name, home, away, date)

    # iterate over odds rows
    for odd in fixture.find_next_siblings("tr"):
        # stop once the next league is met
        if "league" in odd.get("class", []):
            break

        # skipping header rows
        if not odd.td.get_text(strip=True):
            continue

        cells = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in odd.find_all("td")]
        print(cells)
```

Comment: Thanks alot..Had to re-read the Beautiful Soup documentation to understand your code..Second day after I registered here and cant feel more welcome...Btw, check out the way I modified your code..

Answer (score 0):

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.elitebetkenya.com/coupon.php?d")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

docu =  soup.prettify()

for i in soup.findAll("tr"):
    tds =  i.findAll("td")

```
try:
    home = i.find("span", {"class" :"home"}).get_text(strip=True)
    away = i.find("span", class_="away").get_text(strip=True)
    string = tds[0].text
    g= [home,away,"vs"]
    for i in g:
        string.replace(i, "")


    print string


    # print "%s vs %s" %(home,away)
except:
    pass
try:


    if len(tds[0].text)  != 0:



        print " Type: %s Choice: %s, Match code: %s, 1: %s, 0: %s 2: %s" % \
          ( tds[0].text,tds[1].text, tds[2].text,tds[3].text, tds[4].text, tds[5].text)

except:
    pass
```